# Elasticsearch term filter not working?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I'm trying to do the following term filter

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": "terry harvey"
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm getting 0 hits

```
{
  took: 3
  timed_out: false
  _shards: {
  total: 5
  successful: 5
  failed: 0
}
hits: {
    total: 0
    max_score: 0
    hits: [ ]
  }
}
```

When I used the "match filter" instead "term filter", I get 48 hits.

What am I doing wrong? =(

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Term queries and filters are not analyzed, meaning they will only find exact matches.  On the other hand, match queries are analyzed and your name field is probably being analyzed as well.     More info [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_exact_values_vs_full_text.html#_exact_values_vs_full_text).

Comment: I see but how can I do to get a document with the exact name like "terry harvey"?

Comment: You would need to change your field mapping to [not_analyzed](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_literal_index_literal).  If you need to query by both exact values and full text, then you should look into the [multi field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_multi_fields_3) type.

Comment: another good reference http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html

Comment: i have been using index: "not_analyzed" but still not searching for capital letter strings ??

Answer (score 1):

I am using ElasticSearch 8.7 and changing query to

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "name.keyword": "terry harvey"
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

worked.

Mapping for field name was

```
    {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
```